# Retrieve JSON Array element in ReactJS

Tags: json

I have the following json file in ReactJS:

```
{
  "locations": [
      {
        "id": 8817,
        "loc": "NEW YORK CITY"
      },
      {
        "id": 2873,
        "loc": "UNITED STATES"
      },
      {
        "id": 1501
        "loc": "NEW YORK STATE"
      }
    ]
}
```

How can I get the value of a an element where the id=xxxx? Also how can I get the `loc` when id=xxxx?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with react. But if you're using a library like lodash, you can do `const loc = locations.filter(i => i.id === XXXX)`

Comment: I would recommend to start with the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/133645

Comment: Why do you need a library to be able to filter?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli You don't. I forgot to delete that part and now i can't edit the comment. The example i wrote isn't using lodash, it's using the standard Array.filter

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter function.

```js
var obj = {
  "locations": [
      {
        "id": 8817,
        "loc": "NEW YORK CITY"
      },
      {
        "id": 2873,
        "loc": "UNITED STATES"
      },
      {
        "id": 1501,
        "loc": "NEW YORK STATE"
      }
    ]
}
var val = '8817';
var res = obj.locations.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id == val;
  });

  console.log(res[0].loc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use underscorejs

```
let array_of_ids = _.pluck(json_object.locations,"id")

//now find the index of your particular id

let index = _.indexOf(array_of_ids,yourId)

//now your required object is

let your_object = json_object.locations[index]
```

Thats it

cheers